# Change Jupyter notebook name within Watson Studio project

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ibm-cloud

Is there any way to rename a Jupyter notebook within a project on Watson Studio?

Answer (score 7):

1. open the notebook
2. on the right side choose the (i) Info tab
3. change the name there

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, if you wanted to modify the name of your project (not the Jupyter Notebook), you would use the (i). This time, though, you would first visit your projects folder, then click on the project that name you want to modify. Then, without opening any of your notebooks, click the (i) symbol in the upper right corner to rename your project. To update your Notebook's name, simply follow @GM74's remark .